# Angular ng-class renders correct class but Karma shows ERROR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to go beyond an example given in the book AngularJS - Up and Running, and rendering the results in the HTML. The original code can be found here: [Book example (controller.js and controllerSpec.js](https://github.com/shyamseshadri/angularjs-up-and-running/tree/master/chapter3)

The problem is that if I use this code, Karma shows SUCCESS, but classes in HTML are not rendered as expected (all posts are shown with a class ".read", as if both were "read = true;"):

```
angular.module('blogApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [function() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = [
            {title: 'First post', read: false},
            {title: 'Last post', read: true}
        ];

        self.getPostClass = function(status) {
            return {
                read: status.read,
                pending: !status.read
            };
        };
}]);
```

BUT, if I change the returning values to this:

```
return {
    read: status,
    pending: !status
};
```

It loads the correct classes, but Karma shows there are ERRORS. Like this:

```
Chromium 39.0.2171 (Ubuntu) Controller: MainCtrl should have highlight items based on state FAILED
Expected { title: 'Last post', read: false } to be falsy.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/estevan/teste/js/scriptSpec.js:28:30)
Expected false to be truthy.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/estevan/teste/js/scriptSpec.js:29:33) Chromium 39.0.2171 (Ubuntu): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.023 secs / 0.021 secs)
```

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="blogApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Blog App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">

  <div ng-repeat="post in ctrl.posts"
       ng-class="ctrl.getPostClass(post.read)">
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <!-- It used to have an author -->
    <p ng-show="post.author"
       ng-bind="post.author">
    </p>
  </div>

  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the test (scriptSpec.js):

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
  // Instantiate a new version o my module before each test
  beforeEach(module('blogApp'));

  var ctrl;

  // Before each unit test, instantiate a new instance of the controller
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl');
  }));

  it('should have items available on load', function() {
    expect(ctrl.posts).toEqual([
      {title: 'First post', read: false},
      {title: 'Last post', read: true}
    ]);
  });

  it('should have highlight items based on state', function() {
    var post = {title: 'Last post', read: true};

    var actualClass = ctrl.getPostClass(post);
    expect(actualClass.read).toBeTruthy();
    expect(actualClass.pending).toBeFalsy();

    post.read = false;
    actualClass = ctrl.getPostClass(post);
    expect(actualClass.read).toBeFalsy();
    expect(actualClass.pending).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're passing in your post as {title: 'Last post', read: false}. Which is making your return value this for the second one:

```
actualClass  = {
    read: {title: 'Last post', read: false},
    pending: false
}
```

Because of this

```
expect(actualClass.read).toBeFalsy();
```

Will obviously fail as actualClass.read is an object. Same with:

```
expect(actualClass.pending).toBeTruthy();
```

As actualClass.pending is false.

To see what I mean, drop in a console log after each actualClass = like so:

```
it('should have highlight items based on state', function() {
    var post = {title: 'Last post', read: true};

    var actualClass = ctrl.getPostClass(post);
    console.log(actualClass);
    expect(actualClass.read).toBeTruthy();
    expect(actualClass.pending).toBeFalsy();

    post.read = false;
    actualClass = ctrl.getPostClass(post);
    console.log(actualClass);
    expect(actualClass.read).toBeFalsy();
    expect(actualClass.pending).toBeTruthy();
});
```